# How to disable seeking forward on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

In our iPad app, we would like to not allow the users to seek forward using the scrub bar in MPMoviePlayerController for some videos.
Can anyone provide any solution as to how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it eliminates the other controls, but you could write your own - set `MPMoviePlayerController`'s `controlStyle` property to `MPMovieControlStyleNone`.