# How to disable fast forwarding in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have used this

```
[player.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

I have to disable fast forward on the video; how do I do this?

Comment: Welcome Ravi.  _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: Do you mean seek forward??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319726/how-to-disable-seeking-forward-on-mpmovieplayercontroller

Comment: I want to disable moving Slider.... can it possible